# Can I create a Git Pull Request that only includes commits for an individual developer or work item?

Tags: git, github

I would like the ability to build a Pull Request that includes commits from each developer or a specific work item. I typically create a branch for each work item that I am addressing.  But I often find that additional commits (from other developers and work items) appear when I create a Pull Request.

For example, I have a commit that consists of changes to one-and-only-one file.  When I do a Pull-Request, the Pull-Request balloons to an additional four commits with an additional 40 files.

My steps are below.

1. Create a new local branch from my remote master branch.
2. I edit one-and-only-one existing file.
3. I save my changes to the edited file.
4. I Push my change from my local branch to the origin branch.  This creates a commit with changes to the one-and-only-one file.
5. I do a Pull Request.

I now have four additional commits and a total of 41 files.

Is there a way to build Pull Requests to include only commits for an individual developer?

I would also like to use a separate branch; specifically for merging commits from multiple developers and work items.

Are there third-party tools that are especially good at allowing developers to remove commits from a Pull Request?  I'm especially interested in a tool that would simplify Git and reduce the time lost to Git issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem there is that you started working from a branch that is different from the branch that you are asking your PR to be merged into.... that's why you see those *other* revisions. You might skip this problem by rebasing your branch... suppose that it's called `X` and you want to merge it into `origin/master`:

```
git rebase --onto origin/master X~1 X
git push --force origin X # replace the old X on the server with the new X
```

Now the PR should only contain your revision.